# Error when running js discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried making a discord bot in js. I had help but I still done something wrong.
When running it I get the next error in console:

```
undefined:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Erkaloth\Dropbox\Novel Notifier Bot\app.js:7:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

The complete code without token is:

```
// Calling the package
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var fs = require('fs');

//This calls the file named userData.json from the folder Storage.
var userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Storage/userData.json', 'utf8'));


// Listener Event: Message Received (This will run everytime a message is received)
bot.on('message', message => {

    // Variables
    var sender = message.author; // The person who sent the Message
    var msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    var prefix = '~' // The prefix used when writing commands in chat.

    // It checks to make sure the sender is not the bot.
    if (sender.id === '410841116175368193') { // Checks if the ID of the sender is the same ID as the bot.
      return; // Cancels the rest of the Listener Event.
    }

    // Ping / Pong command.
    if (msg === prefix+ 'PING') {
      message.channel.send('Pong!') // Sends a message to the channel, with the contents: "Pong!"
    }

    // This will ban specified words.
    if (msg.includes('FUCK')) { // Checks if the word Fuck is included in the message.
        message.delete()
        message.channel.send('Word used not allowed.')
    }

    if (msg === prefix + 'USERSTATS') {
      message.channel.send('You have sent **' + userData[sender.id].messagesSent + '** messages!')
    }

    //Makes sure the username is in userData before writing to the file.
    if (!userData[sender.id]) userData[sender.id] = {
      messagesSent: 0
    }

    userData[sender.id].messagesSent++; //This adds one to 'messagesSent', under the user.

    //This one saves the file that was wrote in.
    fs.writeFile('Storage/userData.json', JSON.stringify(userData), (err) => {
      if (err) console.error(err); //This one sends a messages with the error to the console if there is one.
    });

  });

  // Listener Event: Bot Launched
  bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Loading...");
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Bot has been loaded completely.");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Welcome, Master!");
    }, 2000);

    // Status
    bot.user.setStatus('Online') // You status goes here; It can be 'Online', 'idle', 'invisible', & 'dnd'

    // Game & Streaming
    bot.user.setGame('~help') // You can change the string to whatever you want it to say.

    //To set a stream, add another option like this:
    //bot.user.setGame('~help', 'https://twitch.tv/user');
    //It has to be a twitch stream link.

    // Any code can be placed here. It will automatically run when the bot starts.
  });

// Listener Event: User joining the discord server.
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User ' + member.user.username + ' has joined the server!') // Sends a message in the console that someone joined the discord server.

    var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'Member [Commoner]'); // This looks for the role in the server(guild), it searches by name, meaning you can change 'Member [Commoner]' to the role you want.

    // Secondly, we will add the role.
    member.addRole(role)

    // Sending a message to a channel when a user joins discord.
    member.guild.channels.get('399321101663993856').send('**' + member.user.username + '**, has joined the server!') // The first part gets the channel, the seconds sends a messages in the respective channel.
});

// Listener Event: User leaving the discord server.
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {

    member.guild.channels.get('399321101663993856').send('**' + member.user.username + '**, has left the server!') // The first part gets the channel, the seconds sends a messages in the respective channel.
});

  // Login
  bot.login('TOKEN FOR BOT HERE')
```

Then again, sorry if I wasn't supposed to post here but I don't know where to search anymore. I have spent a few hours just trying to find a solution and I couldn't find anything. Either that or I am just straight dumb enough not to find it.

Comment: That error means that the JSON it tried to read is not valid. You might have a missing semicolon or quotes or something.

Comment: It seems like calling `fs.readFileSync('Storage/userData.json', 'utf8')` produces an incorrectly formatted JSON string. Can you perhaps share what is stored in file 'Storage/userData.json'?

Comment: There's literally nothing stored at the moment in userData.json the bot was supposed to write something when you type something in chat.

Comment: Maybe you can add some dummy text in `userData.json`, and see if your code gets past line 7, where that error is coming from

Comment: Thanks, @BlunderingPhilosopher, that was the problem, I tried adding manually what was supposed to be in the JSON file and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I added some dummy text in userData.json and it worked.